# Coefficient of $x^7$ in the Taylor series expansion about origin.

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Write down the coefficient of $x^7$ in the Taylor series expansion  of $f$ about the origin.

I first integrate $f'(x)$ and applying $f(0)=0$ get $$f(x)=\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|$$ Then I find $f''(x)$, $f'''(x)$, and so on. But actually at last I failed to compute. In the previous problem it was simply for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ , so I have done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Binomially expand $f'$ and then integrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*} 
f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = (1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \cdots + \frac{( -\frac{1}{2} ) ( -\frac{3}{2} )( -\frac{5}{2} )}{3!} (x^2)^3 + \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Integrate this
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f(x)  = \cdots + \frac{?}{?} x^7 + \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}